# Filter content in shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, shortcode

So, im kinda new to this shortcode but i've almost got working what i need now. (check below of the code)

I would like to filter my content within my shortcode, i'm having a CPT with fields added by the ACF plugin. Now what i need is when i place [speaker_overview_2017 year=2017] it shows only the items with value 2017, and when i'm doing [speaker_overview_2017 year=2018] only 2018, and when i'm doing [speaker_overview_2017] it show's all the items.

Here is my shortcode code, could someone help me out with this?

```
add_shortcode('speaker_overview_2017', 'speakers_overview_shortcode');

function speakers_overview_shortcode($atts){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'qp_speakers',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'orderby'               => 'menu_order',
        'order'                 => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'        => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'speakers_jaar',
                'value' => '2017',
            )
        )
    );

    ob_start();

    $locaties = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $locaties->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $locaties->have_posts() ) : $locaties->the_post(); ?>
            <?php q2_speakers_template(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <?php endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: edit the question to show us the real code you test because this code cannot work, there is twice "return". then if you put `year=2018` in the shortcode, you will retrieve it in `$atts`

Comment: mb, the 1st return wasn't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year attribute you added to shortcode `[speaker_overview_2017 year=2017]` will be available through `$atts` in this way `$atts['year']`. I assume, you want to do a meta query and the key is `speakers_jaar` and the value will be `$atts['year']`. Please check the following code. *When a year is set in shortcode, query will be limited to that year otherwise not limited.*

```
function speakers_overview_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'year' => ''
    ), $atts );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'qp_speakers',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    if ( ! empty( $atts['year'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'speakers_jaar',
                'value' => absint( $atts['year'] ),
            )
        );
    }

    $locaties = new WP_Query( $args );

    ob_start();

    if ( $locaties->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $locaties->have_posts() ) {
            $locaties->the_post();
            q2_speakers_template();
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'speaker_overview_2017', 'speakers_overview_shortcode' );
```

Comment: excellent mate, exactly what i needed. You missed a ; tho in your code, but it's fine, it's working :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked perfectly except the ; :D